# Approach for user who won't add important qualifications to answer?

Tags: discussion

Encountered an answer which advises someone to provide name, date of birth, and address to a company which is contacting him out of the blue.

Further (based on chat discussions with the answerer), the answer is based on the assumption that the OP has incorrectly reported events.

I've asked the answerer to edit the answer to point this out.  He hasn't.  What is the right approach?

Comment: Note - I'm boarding a transpacific plane now.  Won't be able to respond to followup for a while.

Answer (score 7):

Joel, your answer has been voted +10 vs the answer you don't care for, at -10. I believe that says the system works. Higher scored members can vote to delete the answer, but no one should be bullying him to edit his writing. 
The right approach is to move on, the question will be off the first page shortly.